# SHA-256 Padding

Tags: algorithm, sha

To calculate the SHA-256 hash I need to pad my message. Am using the following description:
(taken from http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/shs/sha256-384-512.pdf)

> Pad the message in the usual way: Suppose the length of the message M,
>   in bits, is l. Append the bit "1" to the end of the message, and then
>   k zero bits, where k is the smallest non-negative solution to the
>   equation l+1+k  448 mod 512. To this append the 64-bit block which is
>   equal to the number l written in binary

But what should one do if the message length in bits is less than 64-bits short of a 512bit block... i.e., there isn't room for the end 64-bit block mentioned above? Or the 64-bit length and the "1" bit?

I had a look on wikipedia too, but this doesn't throw any more light on the subject. Google searches haven't been too fruitful either, would appreciate any suggestions :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your message is only just short of a full block (less than 65 bits short), you will need your output to be a block longer than your input. In the worst case, if your message is exactly 64 bits short of a full block, you will add a `1` and then 511 `0`s before the "number" bits, but that is how the padding has to work.

Comment: Super, thanks Rawling. Do you have a reference for that by any chance?

Comment: Well, if `l = 448` (say), the solution to the equation in the spec gives `k = 511`. Since the spec says to add your `1`, your 511 `0`s, and your 64-bit binary representation of `l`, you can't really do anything _except_ have another block in your output.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Good luck with the rest of your implementation!