# Calculating k for padding of SHA-256 message

Tags: algorithm, hash

I'm implementing the [SHS](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf) SHA-256 algorithm in `VHDL` and I am having trouble coming up with a way to solve the equation for **k** when padding the message with zeroes.  The equation is outlined in the SHS description as follows:

> Append the bit “1” to the end of the
>   message, followed by **k** zero bits, where **k** is the smallest, non-negative solution to the equation
>   `l + 1 + k ≡ 448mod512`.

I've seen the equation `k = 448 - (l mod 512 + 1)` which works if `l mod 512` is less than or equal to 448, but if it is larger you get a negative number for k.  I understand in this case we just need to append the "1", pad with "0"s until we hit 512, and then pad with 448 more zeroes followed by the 64 bit binary representation of the message length.

A similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983301/sha-256-padding) is answered with an example:

> Well, if l = 448 (say), the solution to the equation in the spec gives k = 511

I understand where 511 came from, but I can't figure out exactly how I can change the equation to get this number.  Using the equation from above results in `k = -1`.  I realize I could add 512 to the resultant k in the case that k is negative, and this will get me the right answer.  However, I'd like to know if there is a single line equation that can avoid having to check for that.

Thanks!

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) **Some questions are still off-topic,...** 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Care to explain in what way my question is off-topic / unclear?

Comment: How to implement padding in a hardware model in VHDL depends on implementation details, does the model stream? How wide is the interface?    Further see [SHA-256 in FPGA](http://teal.gmu.edu/courses/ECE646/project/reports_2002/IS-2_report.pdf) II. SHA-256 Description, B. Preprocessing, noting in a streaming model this isn't preprocessing, rather what you do when you hit the end of the input stream. The moral is don't think of VHDL as a general purpose programming language, it describes hardware.

Comment: Although I mentioned I was using VHDL, the question I asked wasn't really language or implementation-specific at all.  I was just trying to understand how to derive the value.  Perhaps I should not have mentioned I was using VHDL, as this was more of a conceptual question.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I can just add 512 to the rhs of the equation and then mod the entire thing by 512 as such:

`k = (512 + 448 - (l mod 512 + 1)) mod 512`

This takes care of the negative answer.